# Should I say "I am caught" or "I have been caught" in this situation?

Tags: word-choice, tense

I am playing Subway Surfers and the police officer catches me. 
What do I say now?

> I am caught by the police officer.

Or

> I have been caught by the police officer.

Comment: I am caught by the police officer whenever I do that.

Answer (score 2):

I think the second phrase is correct. You should say:

> I have been caught by the police officer.

The explanation is as follows: the Present Simple Passive expresses a usual or constant action, which is not our case. In our case we have an action which has just ended and we have the result (the police office has caught you, so you have been caught by him). The appropriate tense is Present Perfect Passive.

Comment: Thank you but can i alternatively say i have got caught by the police officer?

Comment: Simple past is also fine, "I was caught by the police officer".  Simple past is also better with "got", "I got caught by the police officer".

Comment: There is no reason to say have been caught here. It just sounds like a foreigner speaking English even though it it not technically a mistake.

Comment: OK, maybe Past Simple here will be better. For some reason, when I was saying or writing "he fell", "he broke his leg" (e. g. in tests), the professionals corrected me and said: "You are wrong, the correct way is to say He has fallen, He has broke his leg."

Comment: @Alex89 - If a professional told you to say "He has broke his leg", then you should look for a new professional.  (It should be "He has **broken** his leg.")  Neither tense is *wrong*, it's just that they mean slightly different things, and confusion about when to use each is one of the most common issues we see here.

Comment: How past simple can be used here when the action has just ended and influences the present?

Comment: @user51260 -  You can always use the simple past.  Present perfect just emphasizes the connection to the present.